# How do I resolve a characteristic write failure on Android & Nordic nRF51?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I am trying to get an Android Nexus 5X app to work with an NRF51 chip, and facing some problems, specifically with writing to a characteristic. Really hope to get some help.

I am trying to set a real-time clock (RTC) on the nrf by means of the app. Details given to me about the GATT service characeristic are as follows:

Properties: Read - Mandatory, Write - Mandatory, WriteWithoutResponse - Excluded, SignedWrite - Excluded, Notify - Excluded, Indicate - Excluded, Writeable Auxilliaries - Excluded, Broadcast - Excluded.

Security: ENC_NO_MITM

Descriptors: None

After connecting to the nrf, my implementation of 'onServiceDiscovered()' is as follows. I was able to do a readCharacteristic, which led to the invocation of 'conCharacteristicRead()', but writeCharacteristic() failed. Will appreciate any guidance. Many thanks!

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

   // Get the characteristic 
   BluetoothGattCharacteristic loggingRTCCharacteristic = gatt.getService(loggingServiceUUID).getCharacteristic(loggingRTCControlPointCharacteristicUUID);
    // Read characteristic (which succeeded, as onReadCharacteristic is invoked)
    boolean successFlag = gatt.readCharacteristic(loggingRTCCharacteristic);

    // Check for success. 

    // Set a plausible timestamp.
    int year_lsb = 221; int year_msb = 7;
    int month = 3;
    int dayOfMonth = 4;
    int dayOfWeek = 7;
    int hour = 9;
    int min = 3;
    int sec = 15;

    byte[] timeStamp = {(byte)year_lsb, (byte)year_msb, (byte)month, (byte)dayOfMonth, (byte)dayOfWeek, (byte)hour, (byte)min, (byte)sec};

   logingRTCCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);

    // This returns a failure. The onCharacteristicWrite() function is not invoked either.
    successFlag = gatt.writeCharacteristic(loggingRTCCharacteristic); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have missed the below line.

```
logingRTCCharacteristic.setvalue(timestamp)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out. I did do so in my original code, but forgot that in the example snippet above. The issue was the fact that I had to wait for the read callback before doing a write characteristic. However, After getting a write success, I got an error - Error 133 during the onWriteCharacteristic() callback.Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Android Ble stack can not handle parallel requests. Hence we need to serialize read/write requests to ble stack. Please make sure your requests are serialized that means you need to wait for few sec or for response before sending next request. You can use delays or queue to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I tried only using readcharacteristic() and it worked, so thanks for that. Am I correct in saying that I need for the callback onWrite/ReadCharacteristic() to occur before proceeding with other BLE methods?

Comment: Yes you can say that. Please upvote my answer in case it is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

ensure that the characteristic data does not exeed the 23 bytes MTU limit. Since the nordic stack (SoftDevice) for nRF51 devices support only a maximum MTU size of 23 bytes. Your data size exeed the 23 bytes.